# how to scan field&method annotations with ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) 5.0.4, I'm trying to find a class' fields and methods having a specific annotation.  I like to avoid having to load the class to not worry about dependencies.
So far, I can't figure out how to get a hold of the field/method annotations with this approach:

```
class AnnotationScanner extends ClassVisitor{

    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible){
        System.out.println("visitAnnotation: desc="+desc+" visible="+visible);
        return super.visitAnnotation(desc,visible);
    }

    public void visitAttribute(Attribute attr){
        System.out.println("visitAttribute: attr="+attr);
        super.visitAttribute(attr);
    }

    public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, Object value){
        System.out.println("visitField: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+desc+" signature="+signature+" value="+value);
        return super.visitField(access,name,desc,signature,value);
    }

    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions){
        System.out.println("visitMethod: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+desc+" signature="+signature+" exceptions="+exceptions);
        return super.visitMethod(access,name,desc,signature,exceptions);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        for (String arg : args){
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(arg));
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
            cr.accept(new AnnotationScanner(Opcodes.ASM4),0);
        }
    }
}
```

The entire sample project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/m2spring/asm-eval).

Running it against a simple class

```
@MyClass(name="annotation scanner")
public class Scannee{
    @MyField(name="a string field") public String aStringField;
    @MyMethod(name="a method")      public void aMethod(){}
}
```

gives

```
visitAnnotation: desc=Lorg/springdot/sandbox/asm/MyClass; visible=true
visitField: access=1 name=aStringField desc=Ljava/lang/String; signature=null value=null
visitMethod: access=1 name=<init> desc=()V signature=null exceptions=null
visitMethod: access=1 name=aMethod desc=()V signature=null exceptions=null
```

but not the annotations of the field and the method.

How can I also get the field and method annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to subclass [`FieldVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/FieldVisitor.html) and [`MethodVisitor`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) and override the method `visitAnnotation`, similar to your `ClassVisitor` subclass. For example,

```
class FieldAnnotationScanner extends FieldVisitor {
    public FieldAnnotationScanner() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
        System.out.println("visitAnnotation: desc="+desc+" visible="+visible);
        return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
    }
}

class MethodAnnotationScanner extends MethodVisitor {
    public MethodAnnotationScanner() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
        System.out.println("visitAnnotation: desc="+desc+" visible="+visible);
        return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
    }
}
```

Then connect them to your `AnnotationScanner` in `visitField` and `visitMethod`. For example, change your code to

```
@Override
public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, Object value){
    System.out.println("visitField: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+desc+" signature="+signature+" value="+value);
    return new FieldAnnotationScanner();
}

@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions){
    System.out.println("visitMethod: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+desc+" signature="+signature+" exceptions="+exceptions);
    return new MethodAnnotationScanner();
}
```

Comment: Incorporated the solution snippets into the [sample code](https://github.com/m2spring/asm-eval/commit/b31666b208db33cfaa8b5d285e085799d7d3da2a). It works.

Answer (score 1):

[The example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458291/4198170) doesn't show how tho access the `name` value of the `@MyMethod` annotation (`name="a method"`). To also read the `a method` value, you have to add two more *Visitors*:

```java
static class MethodAnnotationScanner extends MethodVisitor {
        MethodAnnotationScanner() { 
          super(Opcodes.ASM8); 
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
        System.out.println("visitMethodAnnotation: type= " + desc);
        return new MyAnnotationVisitor();
    }
}
```

```java
static class MethodAnnotationValueScanner extends AnnotationVisitor {
    MethodAnnotationValueScanner() { 
        super(Opcodes.ASM8); 
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(String name, Object value) {
        System.out.println("visitMethodAnnotationValue: " + name + " = " + value);
        super.visit(name, value);
    }
}
```

And insert them by changing retruning the `MethodAnnotationScanner` int the `visitMethod`:

```java
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    System.out.println("visitMethod: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+desc+" signature="+signature+" exceptions="+exceptions);
    return new MethodAnnotationScanner();
}
```

You can see the full updated example here: [how-to-read-a-java-class-method-annotation-value-with-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807758/how-to-read-a-java-class-method-annotation-value-with-asm/61807759#61807759)